# i get resolve as strikethrough in my angular 15 generated project. how can i solve this?

Tags: angular, deprecated, angular-resolver

I'm really new to angular and this is the first project I'm creating. what I need to do here is create an add-editClient component and use the angular resolve method to get data from the backend which is spring-boot and for the database I use MYSQL with DBeaver. I design my interface with angular material.

I added resolve data in the app-routing module as well. no matter how many times I try to install resolve from @angular/router it still gets deprecated.

please see the attached images below.

[addEditClient.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpOwK.png)
[app-routing.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqlbZ.png)

please let me know if there is any way to solve this problem. any suggestions are much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always better to post the code as a text and format it using [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) because image is not very convenient to use and the image link could become unavailable in time. In some cases it's also nice to combine it with tools like [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).
For more info check: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 19):

### Resolve was deprecated in v15.2

And will be removed in v17

As mentioned in the deprecation note of `Resolve` in `@angular/router` it was deprecated in favor of `ResolveFn`.

```
Deprecated: Class-based Route resolvers are deprecated in favor of functional resolvers. 
An injectable class can be used as a functional guard using the 
`inject` function: `resolve: {'user': () => inject(UserResolver).resolve()}`.
```

#### Steps to use the functional resolvers

**Remove** the deprecated `Resolve` implementation from the `addEditClient.ts`

Add this function to your router or the service file or any other file with `export`.
This will inject the `AddEditClientService` and resolve the function you need. As you can see you can also use the `route` and `state` params and pass them to your function.

```
const addEditClietResolver: ResolveFn<any> =
    (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
      return inject(AddEditClientService).getClientById();
    };
```

And use it in the router path

```
{
    path: 'clients/add-edit',
    component: AddEditClientComponent,
    resolve: {data: addEditClientResolver},
}
```

Or with a shorter approach by using the function directly in Route object

```
{
    path: 'clients/add-edit',
    component: AddEditClientComponent,
    resolve: {data: () => inject(AddEditClientService).getClientById()},
}
```

You can checkout more about this in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/ResolveFn)

Comment: Within the `const addEditClietResolver`, how can we get `userId` from storage and make the resolve wait for it and then pass the `userId` to `getClientById()` as an argument? The documentation does not seem to cover examples of this sort. So if you can throw some light on this, that would be super helpful.

Comment: @Devner From what type of storage?

Comment: Ionic Storage. It is available here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage